how to add image of sold product in woocommerce order list?
I am looking to add a thumbnail of the product sold (simple or variable) in the list of orders. This is particularly useful in my variable products to view them without having to open the order. The variations are very different from each other. I tested a mu-plugi that worked well...but...but...this is no longer the case, and I don't understand why
I tested this:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Add Product Image to Orders
Description: Ajoute une colonne avec l'image du produit vendu après le numéro de commande dans la liste des commandes WooCommerce.
Version: 1.1
Author: Votre Nom
*/

// Ajouter une colonne pour l'image du produit après le numéro de commande
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', function($columns) {
    $new_columns = [];
    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
        $new_columns[$key] = $column;
        if ('order_number' === $key) { // Ajoute après le numéro de commande
            $new_columns['product_image'] = __('Image Produit', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
});

// Afficher l'image du produit dans la nouvelle colonne
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', function($column, $post_id) {
    if ('product_image' === $column) {
    $order = wc_get_order($post_id); // Récupère la commande
    if ($order) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    if ($product && $product->get_image_id()) {
// Affiche l'image et arrête après le premier produit
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail', false, ['style' => 'max-width: 50px;']);
                    return;}}}
        // Si aucun produit ou aucune image
        echo '<span style="color: #999;">' . __('Pas d\'image', 'woocommerce') . '</span>';}}, 10, 2);

// Ajouter un style pour ajuster la présentation
add_action('admin_head', function() {
    echo '<style>
    .column-product_image {
    width: 70px; /* Largeur de la colonne */
    text-align: center;}
    </style>';});

